# Elements with animation delay briefly appear before fading in using purely CSS3 Keyframes (no JS)

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

So I want to have a few elements in my header that slide up and fade in on page load using CSS3 Keyframes.  While the animation itself works fine, the elements with a delay on them appear for a split second in their final state before animating.  I currently don't know any JavaScript so I was hoping there is a solution for this purely in HTML/CSS.  Can it be done?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nolder/nrkckt8n/)

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(90, 120, 240);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}

/***************************
HEADER
***************************/

.header-banner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 250px;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 1s;
  -moz-animation: slide-in 1s;
  -o-animation: slide-in 1s;
  animation: slide-in 1s;
  padding: 0 0 60px 0;
}

.header-banner h1,
.header-banner h2,
.header-banner a {
  font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 40px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.header-banner h2,
.header-banner a {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.header-banner h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 1s;
  -moz-animation: slide-in 1s;
  -o-animation: slide-in 1s;
  animation: slide-in 1s;
}

.header-banner h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 1s 0.2s forwards;
  -moz-animation: slide-in 1s 0.2s forwards;
  -o-animation: slide-in 1s 0.2s forwards;
  animation: slide-in 1s 0.2s forwards;
}

.header-banner a {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  background-color: rgb(0, 221, 221);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, .11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  margin-top: 60px;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 1s 0.4s forwards;
  -moz-animation: slide-in 1s 0.4s forwards;
  -o-animation: slide-in 1s 0.4s forwards;
  animation: slide-in 1s 0.4s forwards;
}

.header-banner a:hover {
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(50, 50, 93, .16), 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}


/******************************
KEYFRAMES
******************************/

@-o-keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(40px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(40px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-banner">
    <h1>&lt;h1&gt; element (no delay)</h1>
    <h2>I'm an &lt;h2&gt; element with 0.2s of delay</h2>
    <a href="about.html">I'm an &lt;a&gt; element with 0.4s of delay</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you.  But now the <a> element does not shift up 2px when I hover over it.  When I comment out the keyframes animation call in the **.header-banner a** rule the _transform: translateY(-2px)_ property works again.  Does the keyframes animation nullify this effect or am I missing something?

Comment: That is a different question and so you should ask it separately. For now, you should mark as "accepted" the answer that helped you solve the problem that was asked originally. Click the hollow/empty tick mark below the voting buttons corresponding to the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While the option suggested by Vito is not wrong, it is better to actually achieve this using properties or settings that are specifically designed for this purpose.

The element is visible at start because during the animation's delay period, the properties specified in the `@keyframe` rules will not have any effect on the element. The element would continue to be in the state that is mentioned outside of the `@keyframes`. Here there is no `opacity` specified outside of the `@keyframe` rules and so the default value of 1 is used and the element becomes visible.

Below is what the [CSS specs for Animations say about this](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-animations/#animations):

> Furthermore, ***typically an animation does not affect the computed value before the animation delay has expired*** or after the end of the animation, ***but may do so depending on the animation-fill-mode property***.

Once the animation starts (that is, the delay expires), the element will get the properties specified with in the `@keyframes` rules applied to it (depending on the animation's progress from 0 - 100). So, its first invisible then becomes visible as it slides in.

The way to force the browser to apply the properties specified within the `@keyframes` rules during the delay period is to use `animation-fill-mode` as `backwards`. But in your case, the animation fill mode is already set as `forwards` and ***hence you should change it to*** `both`. A value of `both` means that it will respect the specifications of both `forwards` (that is, hold the state as at last keyframe once the animation is completed) and also of `backwards` (that is, hold the state as at its first keyframe when it's in the delay period).

Below is an extract from the [MDN page on animation-fill-mode property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode):

> **backwards**
>
> The animation will apply the values defined in the first relevant keyframe as soon as it is applied to the target, and retain this during the animation-delay period. The first relevant keyframe depends on the value of animation-direction:
>
> **both**
>
> The animation will follow the rules for both forwards and backwards, thus extending the animation properties in both directions.

In short, the below is what you need to do. Note, the change that I've made at the end of `animation` property's value. I've left out the other properties for brevity, they are present in the demo.

```
.header-banner h2 {
  /* other props removed for brevity */
  animation: slide-in 1s 0.2s both;
}

.header-banner a {
  animation: slide-in 1s 0.4s both;
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */


/***************************************************************

               GENERAL

***************************************************************/

* {
  font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(90, 120, 240);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}


/***************************************************************

               HEADER

***************************************************************/


/*****************************
      BANNER
*****************************/

.header-banner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 250px;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 1s;
  -moz-animation: slide-in 1s;
  -o-animation: slide-in 1s;
  animation: slide-in 1s;
}

.header-banner h1,
.header-banner h2,
.header-banner a {
  font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 40px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.header-banner h2,
.header-banner a {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.header-banner h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 1s;
  -moz-animation: slide-in 1s;
  -o-animation: slide-in 1s;
  animation: slide-in 1s;
}

.header-banner h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 1s 0.2s both;
  -moz-animation: slide-in 1s 0.2s both;
  -o-animation: slide-in 1s 0.2s both;
  animation: slide-in 1s 0.2s both;
}

.header-banner a {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  background-color: rgb(0, 221, 221);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, .11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  margin-top: 60px;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 1s 0.4s both;
  -moz-animation: slide-in 1s 0.4s both;
  -o-animation: slide-in 1s 0.4s both;
  animation: slide-in 1s 0.4s both;
}

.header-banner a:hover {
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(50, 50, 93, .16), 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}


/***************************************************************

              KEYFRAMES

***************************************************************/

@-o-keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(40px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(40px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(40px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(40px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela" rel="stylesheet"

 <header>
   <div class="header-banner">
     <h1>&lt;h1&gt; element (no delay)</h1>
     <h2>I'm an &lt;h2&gt; element with 0.2s of delay</h2>
     <a href="about.html">I'm an &lt;a&gt; element with 0.4s of delay</a>
   </div>
 </header>
```

Comment: great answer, great explanation. I had skimmed the MDN article already but mostly assumed `backwards` referred to the "direction" of the animation or something, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the elements are `visible` and the after the delay when the animation takes places it sets the property to `opacity:0` and on 100% sets to `opacity:1` so you can fix the issue by hiding the elements before load

https://jsfiddle.net/nrkckt8n/3/

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */


/***************************************************************

               GENERAL

***************************************************************/

* {
  font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(90, 120, 240);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}


/***************************************************************

               HEADER

***************************************************************/


/*****************************
      BANNER
*****************************/

.header-banner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 250px;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 1s;
  -moz-animation: slide-in 1s;
  -o-animation: slide-in 1s;
  animation: slide-in 1s;
}

.header-banner h1,
.header-banner h2,
.header-banner a {
  font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 40px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.header-banner h2,
.header-banner a {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.header-banner h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 1s;
  -moz-animation: slide-in 1s;
  -o-animation: slide-in 1s;
  animation: slide-in 1s;
}

.header-banner h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 1s 0.2s forwards;
  -moz-animation: slide-in 1s 0.2s forwards;
  -o-animation: slide-in 1s 0.2s forwards;
  animation: slide-in 1s 0.2s forwards;
}

.header-banner a {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  background-color: rgb(0, 221, 221);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, .11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  margin-top: 60px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 1s 0.4s forwards;
  -moz-animation: slide-in 1s 0.4s forwards;
  -o-animation: slide-in 1s 0.4s forwards;
  animation: slide-in 1s 0.4s forwards;
}

.header-banner a:hover {
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px rgba(50, 50, 93, .16), 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}


/***************************************************************

              KEYFRAMES

***************************************************************/

@-o-keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(40px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(40px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(40px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(40px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela" rel="stylesheet" <header>
<div class="header-banner">
  <h1>&lt;h1&gt; element (no delay)</h1>
  <h2>I'm an &lt;h2&gt; element with 0.2s of delay</h2>
  <a href="about.html">I'm an &lt;a&gt; element with 0.4s of delay</a>
</div>
</header>
```